# Getting My Prometheus instances to show up with labels instead of their instance IP:PORT

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am using Kubernetes and exposing my spring boot services to Prometheus by adding annotations in the deployment.yaml, i have a great dashboard (as seen in the screen shot) the problem I have is when I go to the instance drop down menu to select a different service to view its giving me internal kubernetes IP and Port, i know there are labels attached, is there a way to show a label instead of the IP:PORT as it makes it difficult to figure out what service is what.

[image]

In the prometheus UI i see tags and using one other than instance would make more sense.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config to map your instance:port to meaningful label you need. You would also require to update your query in dashboard accordingly based on what you are relabelling it to